# jQuery show background image only on startpage

Tags: jquery

How can i display a fullscreen, resizing background image only an the startpage.
I have a div in the background that stretches over the full background, resizing on window.load. How can i hide this div unless the current page is startpage?

Comment: Just add the script only on the startpage? Or check if the URI is just /, this should be a no-brainer.

Comment: What exatly is your question about? How to hide the div or how to determine if this is start page?

Comment: Actually yes, the question is how to determine if the current page is start page.

Comment: Then add the script only on the startpage as Veseliq said.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
.pageBg {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   // set background and other properties
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<div class="pageBg">
</div>
<div>
Page content
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
   if(isStartPage()) {
      $(".pageBg").show();
   }
});
```